# Cannot solve observable in google maps callback

Tags: angular, google-maps, rxjs

```
import * as googleMaps from '@google/maps';

constructor() {
        this.googleMapClient = googleMaps.createClient({
            key: 'whatever'
        });
    }
```

// Service to get list of items, call addLocation for each item and return list of updated items.

```
public setItems(): Observable< Item[]> {
         return new Observable(observer => {
             this.getItems()
                 .flatMap((items: Item[]) => {
                     console.log('i get to this point correctly', items);

                     const obs = items.map(item => {
                        return new Observable(observer2 => {
                            this.addLocation(item)
                                .subscribe(data => {
                                    observer2.next(item);
                                    observer2.complete();
                                });
                        });
                    });

                 return Observable.forkJoin(obs);
                })
                .subscribe(data => {
                     observer.next(data);
                     observer.complete();
                });
          });
     }
```

// Service to get location for each item

```
    private addLocation(item): Observable< item> {
            return new Observable(observer => {
            this.getLocationDescription(item.location.latitude, item.location.longitude)

                .subscribe((response: string) => {

                    item.location.description = response;
                    observer.next(activity);
                    observer.complete();
                });
        });
}
```

// Service to get location from google maps

```
private getLocationDescription(latitude:number, longitude: number): Observable<any> {

return new Observable(observer => {

            const latlng = {
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude
            };

            this.googleMapClient.reverseGeocode({
                    latlng: latlng
                }, ((status, results) => {
                    const data = results.json;
                    if (data.status === 'OK') {
                        const locationData = data.results[0];

                        const address = this.extractAddress(locationData);
                        const locationResults: string[] = [];
                        let locationName: string;
                        locationResults.push(this.getFirstDefinedProperty(address,
                            ['neighborhood', 'administrative_area_level_4', 'administrative_area_level_3', 'sublocality', 'route']));
                        locationResults.push(this.getFirstDefinedProperty(address,
                            ['locality', 'postal_town', 'administrative_area_level_2', 'administrative_area_level_1']));
                        locationName = locationResults.join(',');

                        observer.next(locationName);
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(status);
                    }
                })
            );
 });

}
```

// Component

```
    this.itemService.setItems()
                    .subscribe(items => {
                        this.items = items;
// console.log here show the right listt
                    });
```

// Component template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.location.description}}</div>
```

Everything seems to execute correctly and in my component I get the updated list of items with the correct location, but nothing shows in the html.

I have tested returning a simple value instead of the google maps location and everything works, so it seems like the problem is related to the google maps method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `return` before `this.getItems()` :

```
return this.getItems()
```